# EWS singleton for service

Tags: c#, singleton, exchangewebservices

In an EWS application I expect many users(about 100) to be simultaneously on an ExchangeService.

Actually I'm not sure if I should use a singleton for that service or not.
I couldn't find a hint from Microsoft if ExchangeServices should be used as a singleton or not.

What would be the disadvantage of creating a new ExchangeService-connection every time somebody uses the application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run your application within a single class and make sure you use impersonation if you want to hold 100+  users.

Then create a dictionary of Exchange service connections  and subscriptions